# Make Buffer List take focus?

Tags: buffers, customize, focus

How can I make it so that when I press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> to access the Buffer List that that buffer automatically takes focus instead of having to switch to it manually with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>? I can't find a variable that customizes this.

Comment: This is purely editorial, but I have never understood how having the list come up un-focused is supposed to be useful. So yeah, good question.

Answer (score 11):

You can replace the command `list-buffers` which is run with `C-x C-b` to a function that does what you want.  In this case `buffer-menu-other-window` opens the buffers list in another window with focus. Adding the following snippet to your init file should remap `C-x C-b` to the new function.

```
 (define-key global-map [remap list-buffers] 'buffer-menu-other-window)
```

Here `global-map` represents the keymap where `C-x C-b` is bound to a command, `list-buffers` the original command and `buffer-menu-other-window` the new command.

Comment: Or `buffer-menu`, if you don't want to use another window.

Comment: Kudos for using remapping over global-set-key.

Comment: @metaturso You can remap with `global-set-key` as well: `(global-set-key [remap list-buffers] #'buffer-menu-other-window)`. `global-set-key` is merely a thin wrapper around `define-key`.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is to switch to ibuffer, which does not share this problem.

ibuffer is part of GNU Emacs, so on recent versions of Emacs you should just need to add

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

to your init file.

Comment: This is what I do as well, but the wording of your answer makes it seem like it is more than just a matter of preference.

Comment: It certainly does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '((derived-mode . Buffer-menu-mode)
               (display-buffer-reuse-mode-window display-buffer-same-window)))
```

As mentioned by others, switching to `ibuffer` is also an option.